Get same product info while we use catalog_product_save_before and catalog_product_save_after
when i am using catalog_product_save_before and catalog_product_save_after
this two event it will always return catalogue_product_save_before data.
when I am trying to fetch the child id from the parent id, it will give me old child ids instead of updated and other data also
Q:
how we can get updated data if we are use this two event
Code:
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
$usedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);



Put this events.xml in following path.


app\code\Extension\Vendor\etc\adminhtml\events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="your_oberver_name" instance="Extension\Vendor\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>


And create Productsaveafter.php in following path


app\code\Extension\Vendor\Observer\Productsaveafter.php

<?php

namespace Extension\Vendor\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object  
    }   
}


i know that my actual question is when we use event at same time before product save and after product save that time it will give us same data if you fetch the event and and make if condition and then print the both event data it will give you same data
when we print after event data  the data is old before save how we can solve that problem
